# Can a console application in C# can generate a EXE and a DLL?

Tags: asp.net, console-application, windows, class-library

I need to generate an executable file (EXE) to run the application alone and a also generate a DLL because we use tool that perform code analysis.

How can I generate these too files? I have to implement a pos build action?

[image: Options offered by Visual Studio]

Comment: Yes. Please learn [codedom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In fact, I'm not willing to implement a new class structure to my existing application. In other words, I need to build it using Output Type: Console Application and Class Library.

Comment: Yes. you can use CodeDOM to generate binaries (dlls or exe).

Comment: you can create 2 projects, first one is a console application(A) then the second one is code library (B), then you add reference from console to be dependent on B, this will give you an exe of A and dll of B in the same solution, if you want more explanation i will make detailed answer for you, regards

Comment: Hadi Hassan, I got it. The console application will only consume the class library, so I can exec the application and at the same time run the code analysis with the external tool. Tks.